# SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column out of range for INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sqlite, knex.js, node-sqlite3

I want to insert rows into a SQLite3 table using the `knex.raw` method. Unfortunately I get a 'SQLITE_RANGE' error, which makes my test fail.
I have verified the bindings passed to the raw query in the following fashion:

- They respect the order of the INSERT statement
- They respect the specified column types
- They respect the number of bindings requested in the raw query

Beyond that I have looked online, but couldn't find a solution to my issue. Below are the details of the operation attempted:

- **Engine**: [sqlite3 ^3.1.13](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3)
- **SQL Client**: [knex ^0.14.4](http://knexjs.org)
- **Environment**: [electron ^1.7.11](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate)

Error:

```
SQLITE_RANGE: bind or column index out of range errno: 25, code: 'SQLITE_RANGE'
```

Table definition:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `ds13odba`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ds13odba` (
  `SURGERY_CODE` VARCHAR(6) ,
  `TYPE` VARCHAR(1) ,
  `FP59STALIB` VARCHAR(6) ,
  `ID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `createdAt` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL

);

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

*Take note that the column types defined here are *affinity types*, i.e. MySQL types. These are valid in SQLite3 and are casted and optimized by the engine to their equivalent in SQLite3.

Query:

```
INSERT INTO `ds13odba` (FP59STALIB, ID, SURGERY_CODE, TYPE) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `ds13odba` (FP59STALIB, ID, SURGERY_CODE, TYPE) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `ds13odba` (FP59STALIB, ID, SURGERY_CODE, TYPE) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
```

Bindings:

```
[ 
  '047202', 1, '000001', 'D',
  '047203', 2, '000002', 'D',
  '047204', 3, '000003', 'D' 
]
```

Calling code:

```
await knex.raw(...convertToInsertSQL(records));
```

Which resolves to:

```
await knex.raw(insertStatements.join('\n'), bindings);
```

Could you help me with this issue?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue stems from SQLite3's lack of support of multi-statements per exec() call, as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513854/sqlite3-warning-you-can-only-execute-one-statement-at-a-time).

After some testing on my end, I discovered that the **SQLite3 engine will assign automatically all the bindings to the first statement of the prepared SQL**. Any following statements will be ignored.

This still applies for transactions, as the bindings will be applied to the 'BEGIN TRANSACTION;' statement rather than to the following statements.

The solution is to use a compound INSERT statement with bindings.

Hence this:

```
INSERT INTO `ds13odba` (FP59STALIB, ID, SURGERY_CODE, TYPE) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `ds13odba` (FP59STALIB, ID, SURGERY_CODE, TYPE) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
INSERT INTO `ds13odba` (FP59STALIB, ID, SURGERY_CODE, TYPE) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
```

becomes this:

```
INSERT INTO `ds13odba` (FP59STALIB, ID, SURGERY_CODE, TYPE)
  VALUES (?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?), (?,?,?,?);
```

*Bear in mind that compound INSERT statements are only available as of version 3.7.11 of the SQLite3 engine.

Comment: As an extra tip, SQLite3 has a limit of [999 bound parameters per query](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_variable_number)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with the info you've posted, but you haven't posted the actual `.raw()` statements, which would help with debugging.

So attempting to assist, I would suggest that you add an `.on('query-error'`... clause like that below, which will log the SQL that is failing. Many times this will make the problem obvious.

```
knex.raw(...your-stuff...)
    .on('query-error', function(ex, obj) {
        console.log("KNEX-query-error ex:", ex, "obj:", obj);
    })
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your insight, it helped me see the problem from a different angle and will also definitively be a great tool in the future :)